# Why Always return the last array value after an event click on marker leaflet map

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i]["index"] = i;  
}
```

After click to marker , Always return last item

```
marker.bindPopup(popup).on('popupopen',function(e){     
   console.log(marker["index"]);
   //return last item
})
```

Comment: You `let` instead of `var`, it might fix it, it it does I'll explain why

Comment: It's very hard to understand (1) what you want to achieve, (2) what the objects in the code snippets contain and (3) what have you tried.

"last item" -> which item? from where? "last" as in the last element of the array or "last" according to some other metric?

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient details to know why this is happening. Please provide a [mcve] for us to be able to help you. (If using `let` fixes the problem, it would mean that your loop contains more than you're showing here.)

Comment: I changed it to let and it makes the value correct .Thank you , so the problem is what please ?

Comment: @Akxe you must be a mind reader, good job!

Comment: It means [you have a closure inside of your loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). (Which is not what you're showing here.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what is the underlying problem. It is a problem of "closures". It is a complicated topic that a lot of JS developers don't understand.

```js
function withLet() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const expectedI = i;
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('withLet', { expectedI, actualI: i });
    });
  }
}

function withVar() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const expectedI = i;
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('withVar', { expectedI, actualI: i });
    });
  }
}

withLet();
withVar();
```

About why...

The `var` keywork creates the variable in the scope of the function `withVar`. If any function inside of the `withVar` function needs to access the `i` variable it will get the reference shared between all of the iterations of the loop.

All functions, be it event handlers or simple `setTimeout` will thus get the reference of the variable after all synchronous code has run.

The `let` keyword created a new closure, one closure per loop iteration, thus if any function inside the for loop needs to access `i`, it will get the reference of its own and only `i`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const expectedI = i;
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('withLet', { expectedI, actualI: i });
  });
}

console.log(i); // Error! Variable "i" is not defined!
```

Comment: Why add yet another answer to a question that has been asked thousands of times on SO already? There is an [excellent duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for it.

Comment: Because the people don't know what they are looking for when they search it. They see a (to them) unexplainable error.

Comment: Which is why we keep (some) questions as signposts, and mark them as duplicates so all the useful information is in one place. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) Adding yet another answer isn't going to add any value. (In fact, it is only spreading the information, which is what the duplicate system is trying to prevent.)

Comment: Why didn't you marked as duplicate then? I would second you!

Comment: Because I already used my close vote as "needs MCVE" and I can't vote twice. The question itself still lacks the actual details to reproduce the problem they have. There isn't a closure in the for-loop they're showing.